# Mail can't send in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want to send a mail from a server to a Gmail ID, but I get the following message:

> Message: mail() has been disabled for security reasons Filename:
>   libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1554

My code looks like this:

```
$this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email')); 
$from_email= "test.mail@domainame.com";
// $pass = "***********";
$to_email = $this->input->post('email');
$subject='Password Reset Request';
$htmlContent = '<p>'.$link.'</p>';
$this->load->library('email'); 
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from($from_email,'Builders'); 
$this->email->to($to_email);
$this->email->subject($subject); 
$this->email->message($htmlContent);    
  if(!$this->email->send()) {
  //success message
  }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Your host (presumably you're on cheap, shared hosting of some sort) has disabled the function. Ask them to enable it, or change hosts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can only be solved by the hosting company.

Comment: @ceejayoz my code are correct ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter if the code's correct if they've blocked the `mail()` function entirely.

Comment: @ceejayoz tkz sir !!!

Comment: @ceejayoz my server is dedicated server the below code write in cofig that work and send mail  , pls up vote

Comment: You should think about using a proper SMTP server

Comment: Try SendGrid or MailGun API. With an API you would be independent of server (mis)configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your config

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail'; //check on this, which method you want to use smtp/mail/sendmail?
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';  
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

make sure, from address is same as your domain

Comment: It's fairly unlikely that a host that has blocked `mail()` will provide sendmail. They *may* provide an SMTP servers for use, but you'd have to get the details from the host there.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this.*

```
$emailConfig = [
            'protocol' => 'smtp', 
            'smtp_host' => 'XXXXX', 
            'smtp_port' => 'XXXXX', 
            'smtp_user' => 'XXXXX', 
            'smtp_pass' => 'XXXXX', 
            'mailtype' => 'html', 
            'charset' => 'utf-8'
        ];
        $from = [
            'email' => 'a@b.com',
            'name' => 'ab'
        ];
        $message = 'welcome to our site'; 
        $to = array($email);
        $subject = 'welcome';
        $this->load->library('email', $emailConfig);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from($from['email'], $from['name']);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        if (!$this->email->send()) {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        } else {
            echo '<div style="color:green">Email Successfully sent</div>';
        }
```